# Tabbar unbalanced cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i get this error in the console after i push the button.

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for < UITabBarController: 0xcb3a330 >.

my code is

```
-(IBAction)push:(id) sender { 

   UITabBarController *tabbar1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   firstViewController *first = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: first];

   secondViewController *second = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *tabItem2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: second];

   tabbar1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem1, tabItem2,nil]; 

   [self.view insertSubview:tabbar1.view belowSubview: first.view];

   [self presentModalViewController:tabbar1 animated:YES];}
```

the fisrtViewController is UITableViewController

i tried to set the self to `[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:tabbar1 animated:YES];`

but still the same

any idea ?

UPDATE :

i found the solution , i just deleted this line of code

```
[self.view insertSubview:tabbar1.view belowSubview: first.view];
```

and everything went just fine :)

Comment: remove [self.view insertSubview:tabbar1.view belowSubview: first.view]; will fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `[self.view insertSubview:tabbar1.view belowSubview: first.view];` has no significance. Because, the the object `first` is no longer loaded. Therefor that statement is invalid. Remove that code and go on.